# How to replace variable number of placeholders with sequence replacement in r?

Tags: r, gsub, stringr

What I wanted was to replace a placeholder `%f` with vector of sequences. I am currently using the `stringr` function but for each placeholder, I have to add additional replacement vector. The problem is, the number of placeholders in the test string are variable. My code below is not really elegant, and it is fixed to 8 placeholders. Is there any way of making this more dynamic, with `stringr` or any other library?

```
sequence = seq(-10, 10, by = 0.001)

if (str_count(equation, "%f") == 1) {
input_equations <-sprintf(equation, sequence )
}
else if (str_count(equation, "%f") == 2) {
input_equations <-sprintf(equation, sequence, sequence )
}
else if (str_count(equation, "%f") == 3) {
input_equations <-sprintf(equation, sequence, sequence, sequence )
}
else if (str_count(equation, "%f") == 4) {
input_equations <-sprintf(equation, sequence, sequence, sequence, sequence )
}
else if (str_count(equation, "%f") == 5) {
input_equations <-sprintf(equation, sequence, sequence, sequence, sequence, sequence )
}
else if (str_count(equation, "%f") == 6) {
input_equations <-sprintf(equation, sequence, sequence, sequence, sequence, sequence, sequence )
}
else if (str_count(equation, "%f") == 7) {
input_equations <-sprintf(equation, sequence, sequence, sequence, sequence, sequence, sequence, sequence )
}
else if (str_count(equation, "%f") == 8) {
input_equations <-sprintf(equation, sequence, sequence, sequence, sequence, sequence, sequence, sequence, sequence )
}
```

Comment: I think your object equation is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `do.call` function. You will need a list of arguments. So the code is:

```
# Example equation and sequence
equation <- "a + %f - %f"
sequence <- c(1:3)

# Get number of placeholders
str_n <- str_count(equation, "%f")
# Construct arguments list
arg_list <- lapply(c(1:str_n), function(x) sequence)
arg_list$fmt <- equation # Named argument

# Call sprintf with constructed arguments
input_equations <- do.call("sprintf", arg_list)
```

An here is a result:

```
[1] "a + 1.000000 - 1.000000" "a + 2.000000 - 2.000000"
[3] "a + 3.000000 - 3.000000"
```